# Set width of icon specified in content of css

Tags: html, css

I have a code like below.

```
.show:before {
content: '+',
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
}
```

Basically i want to set the width of the `+` icon. But i am not able to. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `,` after `content:"+"` instead of `;` .

Change that and  the width:10px will work. If you want to increase the size of the `+` icon, use font-size

See below

EDIT: after reading your comment i must tell you that `-` and `+` signs ( from the keyboard ) are not the same style of sign. The minus is in fact a `hyphen-minus`. You can read more here > [hyphen minus](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74278/why-is-the-minus-sign-not-on-the-same-height-as-the-plus-sign) .

So. There are 2 possible ways to make this work.

**1.** Use the correct `minus-sign` instead,( not the hyphen minus ) which has the unicode of `U-2212`.

See snippet below

```css
.show:before {
content: '+';
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
font-size:30px;
}
.show:after {
content: '\2212';
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
font-size:30px;

}
```

```html
<div class="show">

</div>
```

**2.** Use FontAwesome for the two icons

```css
.show:before {
content: '\f067';
display: inline-block;

font-size:30px;
font-family:fontAwesome;
}
.show:after {
content: '\f068';
display: inline-block;

font-size:30px;
font-family:fontAwesome;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="show">
blabla
</div>
```

Comment: i got it. I have font-size in my original code. I have - for another class. The width of + and - are not same. Even it font size is same. What could be the exact issue?

Comment: you use font-size in px or in em ? or other ?

Comment: I use font size in px